# Node.JS express API hangs sometimes

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, freeze

I have a web API service written using Node.JS and Express. The service receives requests from web front-end, and sometime it does http request to other web api too by using [`request` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Randomly, I experience issue that the API server simply hangs and never respond. I confirmed that I have changed the default http.globalAgent.maxSockets value by the following code in app.js

```
http.createServer(app).listen(config.http_port);
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = config.http_max_socket //actual value is 1000.
```

I googled further and found this stackoverflow article [node.js http.get hangs after 5 requests to remote site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965582/node-js-http-get-hangs-after-5-requests-to-remote-site). I suspect this might be related to my code to request other services, so I setup a simple express service to test this. In the simple express service, I have a simple api function to mimic my application code:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    request('http://google.com', function(err, resp, body) {
        res.send(body);
    })
});
```

and I set the server maxSocket to be 5

```
http.createServer(app).listen(100);
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 5;
```

I then wrote a small test script to test this:

```
var request = require('request'); 

const url = 'http://localhost:100/test',
    total = 100; 

for(var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    (function(i){
        request(url, function(err, res, data) {
            console.log(i, res.statusCode);
        })
    })(i);
}
```

I was expecting the test to hang after 5 requests but this isn't the case. The test run all the way to the end without issue. So I'm rather confused with the cause why my api sometimes hangs, would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me.

Comment: The reason more than 5 requests are going through is because you use the request library which automatically consumes the response data as soon as it's available and forwards it to your callback. We would need to see your actual code to be able to help you further, and you can retract things that you don't want us to see.

Comment: Thanks, Svenskunganka. At least this helps me to rule out the cause is on my request code. The API code is quite a lot, without knowing which part of the code is causing it to hang, I wouldn't know what to post unfortunately. I shall diagnose this further to update the question I suppose. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Is 1000 a good maxSockets value?

Comment: By default, it is set to `Infinity` according to the [latest documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets). However you probably want some very short-lived caching on the requests you are sending to the API so you can make sure you're not getting rate-limited.

Comment: Hi Lee how did you find which apis is hanging??. I am also facing the same issues